# Change inactive tab color - Material UI Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How do i change the color of the inactive tabs for Material UI tabs?

See in screenshot that they are black.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The right place to do this is in a CSS Stylesheet. From what I can tell, that means button:not(Mui-selected) that advantage of stylesheets is that they are safer: There's really not that much you can break in a CSS Stylesheet, but you can break a lot in a JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hard coded the values with ridiculous colors but the example is sound --  You need to use the `sx={{ }}` *in conjunction with* `style={{ }}`  You can use your theme constants in place of my hard coded values ..  I would have gone further .. But, this is why [We don't use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

```
<Tabs
    value={value}
    orientation={"horizontal"}
    onChange={handleTabChange}
    aria-label="zak example tabs"
    TabIndicatorProps={{
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#0000FF",
      },
    }}
    sx={{
      color: "#FF0000",
      "& button:hover": { background: "#00FF00", color: "#FFF" },
      "& button.Mui-selected": { background: "#FF0000", color: "#FFF" },
    }}
    textColor="primary"
    indicatorColor="secondary"
  >
    <Tab label="Website Traffic" {...a11yProps(0)} />
    <Tab label="Website Metrics" {...a11yProps(1)} />
    <Tab label="Performance Scores" {...a11yProps(2)} />
  </Tabs>
```